# Multiple SSH connections not allowed in an sbt session

Tags: scala, ssh, sbt, scalatest

In a multi-module Scala project I'm running several integration tests where I use `scala-ssh` (v. 0.8) to connect to a remote machine via SSH and transfer a file from there.

If I run an integration test **once** in an `sbt` session, everything works as expected - I can connect to the machine and download any file. The related bits of Scala code are:

```
private lazy val fileInventory: AnsibleYamlFileInventory = {
    val inventory = SSH(ansibleHost, HostResourceConfig()) { client =>
      client.fileTransfer {
        scp =>
          val tmpLocalFile = Files.createTempFile("inventory", ".yaml")
          scp.download(remoteYamlInventoryFile, tmpLocalFile.toAbsolutePath.toString)
          new AnsibleYamlFileInventory(tmpLocalFile)
      }
    }

    inventory.fold(s => throw new RuntimeException(s), identity)
}
```

The problem occurs if I try to run the same test (or another integration test) within the same `sbt` session. I get the same error message as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh#troubleshoting):

```
    14:32:11.751 [reader] ERROR net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Dying because - {}
net.schmizz.sshj.common.SSHRuntimeException: null
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.Buffer.readPublicKey(Buffer.java:432)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.kex.AbstractDHG.next(AbstractDHG.java:75)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:367)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:509)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:107)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:175)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:60)
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognised
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.KeyType$3.readPubKeyFromBuffer(KeyType.java:156)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.Buffer.readPublicKey(Buffer.java:430)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognised
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.common.KeyType$3.readPubKeyFromBuffer(KeyType.java:154)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

If I kill that `sbt` session and relaunch another one, I can again run only a single integration test before the problem reoccurs.

I have already installed the JCE 8 files as suggested. So, I'm wondering what I need to fix to get multiple tests running successfully where one after another they can ssh into that remote machine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you are running and the exact error that you're getting, including the stack trace. Don't link to some github page and make people guess what error you're getting.

Comment: @Kenster, thanks for the comment - I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I found out that the problem was due to `BouncyCastle`, which remains registered as a JCE provider in a follow-up test and causes problems. This shows up in the stack trace as:

```
INFO net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle already registered as a JCE provider
```

I decided to add a [security provider dynamically](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) and remove it after tests are done.

```
def doTests(): Unit = {

  import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  import java.security.Security

  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)

  "Some test" should {
    "be BLABLA" in {
      assert(...) // some test
    }
  }

  "Some other test" should {
    "be BLABLABLA" in {
      assert(...) // some other test
    }
  }

  Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
}
```